# laravel route undefined ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I can't find solution to my Laravel routing error. Whenever I visit the link it shows the error 404 - page not found. Can any body help on this error. Below is my codes-

In web.php

```
Route::get('/post-ads-new/{cat}/{sub_cat}','PostController@postAdsNew');
```

In PostController.php

```
public function postAdsNew($cat,$sub_cat)
  {         

        return view('post-ads-new');
  }
```

And used the url in HTML as

```
<a href="<?php echo $url.'/post-ads-new/?cat='.$category->id;?>&amp;<?php echo 'sub_cat='.$sub_category->subid;?>">
```

Comment: `&amp;` is not valid for the URL. You need to actually use `&`. You really should be building the routes correctly as `/post-ads-new/{$category->id}/{$sub_category->subid}`

Comment: Why don't you  use the format you used in your route? Why url parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Laravel URL generator by adding a name to your route

```php
Route::get('/post-ads-new/{cat}/{sub_cat}','PostController@postAdsNew')->name('ads');
```

And in your view:

Blade version:

```php
<a href="{{ route('ads', ['cat' => $category->id, 'sub_cat' => $sub_category->subid]) }}"></a>
```

Native PHP version:

```php
<a href="<?= route('ads', ['cat' => $category->id, 'sub_cat' => $sub_category->subid]) ?>"></a>
```

Here is the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/urls

Answer (score 1):

The variables are unnecessary in the url, you will need to construct your url like the following:

```
<a href="<?php echo $url.'/post-ads-new/'.$category->id.'/'.$sub_category->subid;?>"></a>
```